# How to fetch all documents from a firebase collection in Flutter using the Riverpod package?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I am using the provider package and have a provider that gets its initial value from a global variable idea which a list of json data and is of type List<Map<String, dynamic>>.

following is the code for that, which is working expected.

```
final ideasListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<IdeaList>((ref) {
  return IdeaList([for (var i in ideas) Idea.fromJson(i)]);
});
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is replace the variable idea and instead use the list of documents I get from a collection I have on firebase.

But I am not sure how to proceed from here onwards.

Here's a second provider that fetches the snapshot form firestore.

```
final firbaseIdeaProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ideas').snapshots();
});
```

What do I do now?
The rest of my code is depended on the ideasListProvider, so I will have to somehow provide it with the a list of the documents from the ideas collection on firebase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good news, you are on the right track. First, what you want to do is likely map your firestore data to your data model. This can be accomplished by creating a new stream mapped from your firestore data stream:

```dart
final firebaseIdeaProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<Idea>>((ref) {
  final stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ideas').snapshots();
  return stream.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Idea.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
});
```

Now all that's left is to read your StreamProvider. An example that will handle loading, error, and new data states could be as follows (with [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod)):

```dart
class IdeasExample extends HookWidget {
  const IdeasExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ideas Example'),
      ),
      body: useProvider(firebaseIdeaProvider).when(
        loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        error: (err, stack) => Center(child: Text(err.toString())),
        data: (ideas) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: ideas.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(ideas[index].toString()),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Without hooks:

```dart
class IdeasExample extends ConsumerWidget {
  const IdeasExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ideas Example'),
      ),
      body: watch(firebaseIdeaProvider).when(
        loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        error: (err, stack) => Center(child: Text(err.toString())),
        data: (ideas) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: ideas.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(ideas[index].toString()),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried this out but it is triggering an exception `[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()` But the thing is I have already initialized Firestore in the mian.dart file. Any Idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you properly await it? `Future<void> main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); ... }`

Comment: Well turns out I did forget to add an await before Firebase.initializeApp(). The code is working properly now. If you could help me with one last this, I also want to use this value inside of another provider, this one to be specific.`final ideasListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<IdeaList>((ref) {
  return IdeaList([for (var i in ideas) Idea.fromJson(i)]);
});` But insted of returning `[for (var i in ideas) Idea.fromJson(i)]` inside the IdeaList, I want to return the list we recieve from the firebaseIdeaProvider. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: It is possible though I'm a bit confused about why you would want to do this. I think there are likely easier ways of accomplishing whatever it is you're trying to do by simply updating your `Idea`s in Firestore and the stream will serve the most up-to-date values, rather than manipulating them locally in a StateNotifier.

Comment: I want to be able to filter the list of ideas when the user clicks a button using an Enum. Before implementing firebase, I was watching the state of the ideasProvider and the enum in a different provider and was displaying the items based on that. So was wondering if that could be done somehow using the value I get from ideaFirebaseProvider?

Comment: @Dexter if you haven't already figured this out, check out the todos list example on the Riverpod site.  I'm just going through this now, it is using Enums to filter.